# Prices on year by year basis

Tags: inflation, data-request, price

I want to know the **cost of milk** on a **year by year basis**, say for the last 10 or 20 years. similarly I may want to know price of other items also (petrol, rice, biryani, etc). I just need the average values. What is the best source of knowing these things. I'm **particular about India**. Please give me any website name or so that provides such statistical data.

Comment: Just to make sure, you want the historical prices of food for India?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Indian **Government's** open data website https://data.gov.in/

I am not sure if all your requirement will be met, but this is a good place to begin your research.

To find the data you require, you might want to use the "search box" on the header.When I searched for "retail milk price" (keywords), I could find several datasets for different timeframes.